# How to ensure a score is calculated correctly in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to verify a calculation is correct in Cypress.

So I have a NextJS application that uses Material UI with the following markup rendered as:

```
<ul data-cy="patientLogList">
 <li>
  <section>
   <h3 class="MuiTypography-root">Symptom Score 1</h3>
   <p class="MuiTypography-root">
    <section>
     <h3 class="MuiTypography-root">Wheezing</h3>
     <p class="MuiTypography-root">Very Mild</p>
    </section>
   </p>
  </section>
 </li>
</ul>
```

So the symptom score looks like so:

```
var symptomScore = [{ 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2, 'Moderate': 3, 'Severe': 4, 'Very Severe': 5 }]
```

So I am trying to come up with a cypress test that checks if the wheezing is at very mild then the symptom score should be 1.

I started with something like this:

```
var symptomSurveys = [
  { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5} 
];
var symptomSum = [];

symptomSurveys.forEach(function(survey) {
    if ()
});

symptomSum;
```

And felt I was going down the wrong path fairly quickly.

Then I thought maybe something like this:

```
var symptomSurveys =
      { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5};

symptomSurveys['Very Mild'] === 1
```

But even if I create a bunch of if conditionals, I still do not know how would this fit in eventually using Cypress methods.

The Cypress code I worked on looked like so:

```
if (symptomScore['Very Mild'] === 1) {
  cy.get('ul[data-cy=patientLogList] li section h3').should('eq', 'Symptom Score 1')
}
```

With your help, I was able to rewrite it like so:

```
var symptomSurveys =
      { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5};

cy.get('[data-cy="Wheezing"]')
    .contains('Wheezing')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(symptom => {
        const matcher = new RegExp(`${symptomSurveys[symptom]}$`) // ends with symptom score
        cy.get('ul[data-cy="SymptomScore 1"]')
            .contains('[data-cy="SymptomScore 1"]', /Symptom Score \d/)
            .invoke('text')
            .should('match', matcher)
    })
```

The HTML I have altered to look like so:

```
<ul data-cy="patientLogList">
 <li>
  <section>
   <h3 class="MuiTypography-root" data-cy="Symptom Score 1">Symptom Score 1</h3>
   <p class="MuiTypography-root">
    <section>
     <h3 class="MuiTypography-root" data-cy="Wheezing">Wheezing</h3>
     <p class="MuiTypography-root">Very Mild</p>
    </section>
   </p>
  </section>
 </li>
</ul>
```

But now I get the following error:

`expected 'Symptom Score 1' to match /undefined$/`

Comment: Can you add your Cypress code that you've been trying?

Comment: @agoff, I added the Cypress code that I last tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it given what you have provided:

```js
var symptomSurveys =
      { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5};

cy.get('ul[data-cy="patientLogList"]')
    .contains('h3.MuiTypography-root', 'Wheezing')
    .siblings('p')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(symptom => {
        const matcher = new RegExp(`${symptomSurveys[symptom]}$`) // ends with symptom score
        cy.get('ul[data-cy="patientLogList"]')
            .contains('h3.MuiTypography-root', /Symptom Score \d/)
            .invoke('text')
            .should('match', matcher)
    })
```

---

Without `ul[data-cy=patientLogList]')` should work as well:

```js
var symptomSurveys =
      { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5};

cy.contains('h3.MuiTypography-root', 'Wheezing')
    .siblings('p')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(symptom => {
        const matcher = new RegExp(`${symptomSurveys[symptom]}$`) // ends with symptom score
        cy.contains('h3.MuiTypography-root', /Symptom Score \d/)
            .invoke('text')
            .should('match', matcher)
    })
```

---

I believe adding `data-cy` attributes only complicates things in your case.
Using `cy.contains()` is still considered the next best thing according to [cypress best practices on selecting elements](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements).

[`cy.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) is really efficient in finding elements. Unless you're working on an app that's available in multiple languages, don't hesitate to use it.
But, you should always use it with a selector to make sure you get the element you wanted, even if it's just a tagName. Otherwise, you might get an element that contains your target element because it also contains the given text.

Here's an attempt to keep it as simple as possible with `cy.contains()`:

```js
var symptomSurveys =
      { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5};

cy.contains('h3', 'Wheezing')
    .siblings('p')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(symptom => {
        cy.log('symptom', symptom) // validate you have the right info
        const matcher = new RegExp(`${symptomSurveys[symptom]}$`)
        cy.contains('h3', /Symptom Score \d/)
            .invoke('text')
            .should('match', matcher)
    })
```

Comment: the one issue with this solution is that it does not find the `ul[data-cy="patientLogList"]` I tried it with and without the quotations around `patientLogList`.

Comment: Both of them or only the 2nd one?

Comment: it cannot find the first one.

Comment: Weird, I took it as is from the code you provided. I edited without it. Works as well

Comment: I could not use those Mui classes because they technically don't exist, its how Material UI works, Cypress did not have Material UI in mind, so I had to add some of my own `data-cy=` to it. Can you take a look because I believe you are on to a solution, but check out the error I get now.

Comment: New edit, don't give up

Comment: with your latest edit, I continue to get `expected 'Symptom Score 1' to mach /undefined$/`

Comment: May I ask what is the output of `cy.log('symptom', symptom)`

Comment: ahh, `Very Mild` is the output. That's why its not matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('p', 'Very Mild')
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('h3').should('have.text', 'Symptom Score 1')
  })
```

The three `parent()` will help you go to the topmost `section`. Then using `within()` we will direct our next commands inside the topmost section. Then using `cy.get('h3').should('have.text', 'Symptom Score 1')` we are validating the **Symptom Score 1**.

In case you want to add forEach() loop, you can do something like this:

```js
var symptomSurveys = {
 'Very Mild': 1,
 'Mild': 2,
 'Moderate': 3,
 'Severe': 4,
 'Very Severe': 5
}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(symptomSurveys)) {
  cy.contains('p', key)
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('h3').should('include.text', value)
    })
}
```

Comment: I think two `.parent()` will only get us to the `p` above? So you'd need a `siblings('h3')` or another `parent()`. `p` -> `section` -> `p`?

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I have added one more `parent `

Comment: @AlapanDas, how does this solution integrate this: `var symptomSurveys =
      { 'Very Mild': 1, 'Mild': 2,'Moderate': 3,'Severe': 4,'Very Severe': 5};`?

Comment: I have updated the answer.